# How to test an MCCB for safe functionality?

Tags: testing, circuit-breaker

Ive got a few MCCBs for an old system, what is a suitable way to test them to make sure that they function correctly and safely?

Comment: Apply a known overload and see if they trip? It’s very unlikely they would have stopped functioning.

Comment: There is a tester used to test rcd’s etc, applies a fault and measures the time to respond.

Comment: Buy new ones. How do you know that the contacts are not eroded nearly to their end-of-life limit. Engineering is not something for trying to cut risky -corners on. Of course, if they are in their original boxes and have data sheets they might be OK but, all the same, I'd read the data sheet and contact the manufacturer to see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is likely much more convenient and economical to simply buy new MCCBs if verification is required and these are common low voltage MCCBs.

MCCBs consists of two "triggers" - a thermal trigger and a magnetic trigger. The characteristics of the MCCB determine the relationship between the two.

To perform a functional test, both features must be independently tested.

Thermal: A current is applied to the MCCB to simulate the effect of overloading the circuit. It is verified that the MCCB triggers within the expected duration as per the characteristics curve of the device.

Magnetic: A pulse is applied to the MCCB to simulate the (much larger) current that would trigger the magnetic trigger. First at an interval below what would trigger the MCCB, whereafter the pulses are increased. The MCCB must trigger the magnetic trigger in accordance with its characteristics.

For example a MCCB with C characteristics must trigger the magnetic trigger at 5...10 times the nominal current (In). So if a C10 MCCB triggers instantly at 40 A or 110 A, both are a failed result.

In both cases, special test equipment is used.

**Notes and limitations**

Note that the above is only a functional test to verify that the device provides the expected protection.

There are many other factors to consider if evaluating whether the device is "safe" or not (as the question is phrased). For example whether the casing is intact and offers the intended protection against touching conductive parts, or whether the impulse voltage is according to ratings. Things like contact resistance, isolation resistance, a mechanical inspection and many other factors are equally important, when the scope is expanded from functional testing ("does it work") to "is it safe?"

Also note that depending on the MCCB, it is possible that testing the device may deteriorate or even consume the MCCB. MCCBs are made in accordance with many specifications, for example IEC 60898 and IEC 60947-2, and many MCCBs are even built and rated for multiple specifications at the same time, but under different ratings.

For example the very same MCCB may be installed in a location where the prospective current is 10 kA in a factory but only 6 kA in a private residence. And some MCCBs may be designed to endure multiple faults whereas others may be designed to offer protection against faults once, but be consumed/destroyed in the process.

Thus, testing it itself can essentially both break or deteriorate an MCCB, depending on its rating and type. And in any case it is greatly important to understand exactly which limitations and intended uses the specific MCCB has, before applying any tests to it.